# QLabel text doesn't update after i changed it when QMainWindow is shown

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qlabel, qmainwindow

I've set a placeholder in a `QLabel` to "user".

After `ui->setupUi(this);`, `QLabel` gets changed via `ui->label->setText("superuser");`. No changes are made afterwards.

As soon as `QMainWindow` is initialized and shown via `mw.show();` in `main.cpp` file , `QLabel` is set to the placeholder "user" again.

I tried:

- `qDebug()<<ui->label->text();` before and after `ui->label->setText("superuser");` and placed one right at the end of constructor of `QMainWindow`.
  Results:

  ```
  user
  superuser
  superuser
  ```
- Checked `mainwindow.ui` in nano, all is right.
- Checked connections: there are no connections that are linked to the function that changes `QLabel`.
- Checked if `mw->show();` is triggered multiple times in `main.cpp`, one call.
- No external thread changes the `QLabel` outside from `QMainWindow`.

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

`mainwindow.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->init();
    qDebug() << "afterInit" << ui->label->text();
}

void MainWindow::init()
{
    this->set_options("SuperUser");
}

void MainWindow::set_options(QString s)
{
    debugInt++;
    qDebug() << debugInt;
    qDebug() << ui->label->text();
    ui->label->setText(s);
    qDebug() << ui->label->text();
}

void MainWindow::on_actionLogout_triggered()
{
    this->set_options("User");
}
```

`mainwindow.h`:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void set_options(QString s);

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    void init();
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    int debugInt=0;

private slots:
    void on_actionLogout_triggered();
};
#endif //MAINWINDOW_H
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true);

    MainWindow w;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

`ui->label` is set to "Current: user" in `mainwindow.ui`. That's the standard set text that I call **placeholder**.

`mainwindow.ui`:

```
<property name="text">
           <string>Current: user</string>
```

My `QDebug` output when I start the program and then press logout:

```
1
"Current: user"
"Current: SuperUser"
"afterInit "Current: SuperUser"
2
"Current: user"
"Current: User"
```

As you can see, by default `ui->label` is set to "Current: user". In the `init` process it gets overwritten to "Current: SuperUser". But when I start the program, it is shown as "Current: user". As soon as I click the `actionLogout` (`menubarbutton` in `mainwindow_ui`), `ui->label` is set to "Current: User" and gets shown right.

**Note:** I created a new program with the given code. Works as it should, `ui->label` isn't changed in any other function in my code.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Are you being confused by a label and e.g. a `QLineEdit` next to each other? What does it mean, to have *set a **placeholder** in a **QLabel** to [...]*?

Comment: Does your last edit say that the code you provided does not reproduce the issue? Because it doesn't, I get "Current: SuperUser" at first, and "Current: User" when I click `actionLogout`. Here's the output: (`1\n"Current: user"\n"SuperUser"\nafterInit "SuperUser"\n2\n"SuperUser"\n"User`)

Comment: It didn´t reproduce the issue. there´s something wrong in my original project, but i cant figure out what it is. The given code is the only code related to ui->label in my original project

Comment: We cannot help you without a minimal **reproducible** example, this is a debugging issue, read the link I provided, and this one [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems), to see where does your label text gets changed, that would at least help your make a minimal **reproducible** example. But for now, I don't think your question is answerable. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

So I´ve found the error. I have overwritten `MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent* event)` method:

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent* event)
{
  if(0 == event) return;

  switch(event->type())
  {
  case QEvent::LanguageChange: ui->retranslateUi(this); break;

  case QEvent::LocaleChange: break;

  default: break;
  }

  QMainWindow::changeEvent(event);

  }
```

**`Fix:`**

I add `ui->label->setText( tr("Current: ") + currentUserString );`
before `QMainWindow::changeEvent(event)` because the `QLabel` gets changed when `MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent* event)` is executed to the set string in .qm/.ts translation file.
Thats why mainwindow showed me "Current: user" (from translation file) instead of "Current: SuperUser" (changed in init function)

new `mainwindow.cpp`

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent* event)
{
  if(0 == event) return;

  switch(event->type())
  {
  case QEvent::LanguageChange: ui->retranslateUi(this); break;

  case QEvent::LocaleChange: break;

  default: break;
  }

  if(uiIsSetUp) //bool that get set true after `ui->setupUi(this);`
    ui->label->setText( tr("Current: ") + currentUserString );

  QMainWindow::changeEvent(event);

  }
```